# ¿Cómo listar usuarios registrados en consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql

Hola amigos tengo un problema en mysql al momento de listar los usuarios.
El problema radica en que ademas de listar los ID de los usuarios también me gustaría listar a los usuarios no solo el ID. Lo detallare en el código.

Aqui es cuando creo la tabla donde se ingresare a los nuevo usuarios

```
#Creo tabla de usuarios
CREATE TABLE users(
       IDuser INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       user VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
       passwd VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
       );
```

Creo la tabla donde los usuarios podrán agregar monedas según vallan teniendo en su inventario
de monedas.

```
#Creo tabla de monedas 
CREATE TABLE monedas(
       IDmonedas INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       IDuser INT,
       monedas BIGINT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (IDmonedas),
       FOREIGN KEY (IDuser) REFERENCES users(IDuser)
       );
```

Altero la tabla de usuario agregando la clave foranea de monedad

```
#Altero la tabla usuarios para asignar la clave IDmonedas
`ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN IDmonedas INT,
 ALTER TABLE users ADD FOREIGN KEY (IDmonedas) REFERENCES monedas(IDmonedas) ;`

#Describo las tablas para ver los resultados
 | Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 | IDuser    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
 | user      | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | passwd    | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
 | IDmonedas | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
 +-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

#Creo al usuario 
 INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, passwd) VALUES ('darkblader' , 'password123') ;

#Ingreso datos en la tabla monedad
 INSERT INTO monedas (monedas) VALUES ('790') ;
```

Resultados después de consulta

```
#Resultado de consulta
 SELECT * FROM monedas ;
 +-----------+-----------+---------+
 | IDmonedad | IDusuario | monedas |
 +-----------+-----------+---------+
 |         1 |      NULL |     790 | #El usuario IDuser darkblader
 +-----------+-----------+---------+ #esta como NULL

#Resultado de consulta como me gustaría tener 
 +-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
 | IDmonedad | IDusuario |  User      | monedas |
 +-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
 |         1 |      1    | darkblader | 790     |
 +-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Gracias amigo se me había escapado la eh agregado. Muchas gracias

Comment: Esto se resuelve con un join, ya trataste algo al respecto?

Comment: No eh intentado con join pero me estaba documentando con union pensé que esa era la forma correcta. Gracias

Comment: Intenta construir el join y si obtienes errores edita la pregunta agregando lo que hayas hecho y te ayudamos

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo disculpa mi ineptitud.

Comment: Como dice @BetaM el tipo de resultado que necesitas según lo explicado se obtiene con `JOIN`,  no con `UNION`, que es para otra cosa. Aparte de eso, en el segundo INSERT te faltó incluir el ID del usuario al que corresponde esa moneda: `INSERT INTO monedas (IDusuario, monedas) VALUES (1, '790') ;`

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos desconocía las funcionalidades de JOIN ya que soy nuevo en la materia pero lo estoy repasando y por lo que me eh documentado es bastante importante. Gracias ya corregí el error de no asignar al usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primer detalle, en el INSERT que haces a la tabla monedas no le estás pasando el id de usuario y por eso el idusuario está a NULL.

Este sería un insert correcto:
INSERT INTO monedas (monedas, IDuser ) VALUES (790, 1) ;

Por lo que entiendo tus tablas tienen una relación 1:1. Por lo que tu primer diseño para mí es correcto. Esos alter no son necesarios para nada.

Si lo que quieres es sacar información del usuario y también la información de su monedero lo que tienes que usar es un `JOIN`

```
SELECT u.user, m.monedas
FROM users u
  INNER JOIN monedas m ON m.IDuser = u.IDuser
WHERE u.IDuser = 1
```

Primero pedimos solo los datos del IDuser 1 (`WHERE u.IDuser = 1`)
Lo siguiente es agregar los datos de la tabla `users` con los datos de la tabla `monedas`, para ello usamos un `INNERJOIN`.

INNERJOIN solo devuelve registros si existen datos en ambas tablas. Hay otros tipos de JOIN pero lo dejo a tu curiosidad mirarlos.

El último paso es decirle que columnas de ambas tablas relacionarán los registros. Como la tabla monedas tiene el ID del usuario usamos ese campo en ambas tablas para unir los datos.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fcdabc/1

Por último decir que para el ejemplo actual que muestras no tiene mucho sentido tener una tabla dedicada. Si solo vas a tener un campo (o unos pocos) es mas efectivo tenerlo en la misma tabla usuarios.

Comment: ¿Por qué el valor de monedas entre comillas?, lo digo por que en la definición de la tabla esta como `BIGINT`

Comment: La tabla id monedas no tiene ningun sentido con una relacion 1 a 1... yo aclararia eso en la respuesta

Comment: actualizadas ambas

Comment: Gracias amigo, yo pensaba que estaba haciendo una relación 1 a muchos. Tendré que repasar las relaciones en bases de datos muchas gracias de ante mano.

Comment: ya lo intente asignar el campo de monedas al usuario, pero cuando hago los formularios tienen que llenar el campo monedas, la idea que pretendo realizar es que el usuario vaya agregando monedas según vaya teniendo y no al momento del registro. Intente dejarlo en blanco al momento de hacer un insert no me dejo hacerlo porque requiere el campo monedas que no puedo dejarlo en blanco.

Comment: @PedroNavajas el dejarlo en blanco o no depende de como definas la tabla. Si permites valores nulos te permitirá dejarlo en blanco. si quieres también puedes poner un default a 0 y por defecto tendrán ese valor cuando no lo añadas. En cuanto 1 a muchos, si es lo que buscabas diría que está bien pero tendrás que hacer el join siempre. Por los ejemplos parecía una relación 1:1 pero podría haberme equivocado en eso :)